# Software for plotting graphs for functions with cases

Tags: math-software

In which software it will be easy to plot the graph of functions like $$f_{2^n+j}(x)=\begin{cases}0, x\in [\frac{j}{2^n},\frac{j+1}{2^n}]\\1, x\in x<\frac{j}{2^n} \text{ or } x>\frac{j+1}{2^n}\end{cases}$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica you can use `Piecewise`

```
f[j_, n_, x_] = 
Piecewise[{{0, j/2^n <= x && x <= (j + 1)/2^n}, {1, x < j/2^n || x > (j + 1)/2^n}}]
```

Comment: when I do as you say I get this (added a pic). How to handle this error?

Comment: I need installed software or I can do it online?

Comment: I downloaded Mathematica. Your code does not work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev The program works for me. What error message do you get? Instead of Mathematica you can use an online graphing calculator like desmos or geogebra (here is the same function using desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dyjnnakdzb. You can move the sliders to test different values of $n$ and $j$)